# Any chance we could change the color of the accepted check mark?

Tags: feature-request, design

I am colorblind and the color difference between accepted and not accepted is nearly indistinguishable. Would it be possible to darken up the accepted color or throw some thing else in there that makes it easier to see?

Probably not a huge deal, but it's been driving me nuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm not color blind, and i have to stare at it a little longer to figure it out, a slightly higher contrasting color might be ideal